# Display doc file in iframe struts2

Tags: java, iframe, struts2, google-document-viewer

I want to show `.doc` and `.docx` files on my website in an iframe.

```
<iframe style="border-style: none;" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=<s:url action="loadFile"><s:param name="id" value="id"/></s:url>" height="500" width="100%">
```

The loadFile action sends a result of type stream

```
<action name="loadFile" class="com.view.file" method="loadFile">
                <result name="success" type="stream">
                    <param name="contentType">${fileType}</param>
                    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
                    <param name="contentDisposition">inline;filename="${fileName}"</param>
                    <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
                </result>
</action>
```

The iframe works when I set the action url directly in the src attribute. However, with `src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=` the action is never called.
Is there any other alternative to show a MS Word file? I'm able to show a pdf by directly putting the action url in src attribute.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The problem may be because the src of iframe converts to:

```
src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=/App/loadFile?id=25"
```

The required url should be the absolute url to the action like:

```
src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://localhost/App/loadFile?id=25"
```

How can I achieve that? It might not work on localhost but should work on a hosting

Comment: Read the docs for `<s:url>` tag: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/url.html.

Comment: Which attribute should I set in the s:url tag to get the complete URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the attribute `forceAddSchemeHostAndPort` of `s:url` tag to get the complete url

[More Info](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html)

For Example

```
<s:url action='myaction' forceAddSchemeHostAndPort='true'>
<s:param name='id' value='25'/>
</s:url>
```